# How to move HTML table elements up or down by using JavaScript and keep the order of all elements intact (i.e. 1,2,3...etc) in the front end?

Tags: javascript, java, html, user-interface, button

I have HTML table with several elements (td tags), each row has 4 buttons, "Edit", "Delete", "Move Up" and "Move Down". The "Move Up" and "Move Down" buttons behave oddly sometimes as their actions can cause several rows to have the same "item_order" in the MySQL database. Thus, when trying to move other rows up or down, the functions won't work as intended because of the duplicate "item_order" for more than one row. When checking the database I can see many rows have "item_order = 1" or 2 or 5 and so on

I would like the "Move Up" and "Move Down" buttons to keep updating the MySQL DB (but hopefully in a proper ordering), AND ALSO to move the rows in the UI front-end so that they appear in the desired order 1,2,3 ...etc

Please be patient with me because I am a newbie in the software development business and I am still learning things.
Below is the table:

```
<tr id="tr_<%=String.valueOf(RowCount)%>" onmouseover="showRow(<%=String.valueOf(RowCount)%>)" onmouseout="hideRow(<%=String.valueOf(RowCount)%>)">
     <td valign="top" width="200px" class="tablepad tableborder_bottom">(<%=String.valueOf(RowCount)%>) <%=topic%></td>
     <td valign="top" width="200px" class="tableborder_left"><%=sub_topic%></td>
     <td valign="top" width="280px" class="tableborder_left"><%=item%></td>
     <td valign="top" class="tableborder_left"><a href="ad_summary.jsp?action=edit&rowid=<%=absid%>&description=<%=item%>&serviceName=<%=sub_topic%>&mainHeading=<%=topic%>" target="_top"><img src="./media/images/edit.jpeg" border="0"/></a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="tableborder_bottom"><a href="ad_summary.jsp?action=delete&rowid=<%=absid%>&description=<%=item%>&serviceName=<%=sub_topic%>&mainHeading=<%=topic%>" target="_top"><img src="./media/images/delete.jpeg" border="0"/></a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="tableborder_bottom"><a href="ad_summary.jsp?action=move_up&rowid=<%=absid%>&itemOrder=<%=item_order%>" target="_top"><img src="./media/images/16_arrow_up.png" border="0"/></a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="tableborder_bottom"><a href="ad_summary.jsp?action=move_down&rowid=<%=absid%>&itemOrder=<%=item_order%>" target="_top"><img src="./media/images/16_arrow_down.png" border="0"/></a></td>
     </tr>
```

Here is the Java code to update the MySQL Database when "move_up" or "move_down" button is used:

```
if (action.equals("move_up")){
  action="add";

  if (whichOrder != 1){
    int CurrentOrder = whichOrder;
    int NewOrder = whichOrder - 1;
    String sqlString1 = "UPDATE msr_summary_notices set item_order = "+String.valueOf(NewOrder)+" WHERE item_order = "+String.valueOf(CurrentOrder);
    String sqlString2 = "UPDATE msr_summary_notices set item_order = "+String.valueOf(CurrentOrder)+" WHERE item_order = "+String.valueOf(NewOrder)+" AND absid <>"+rowid;
    statement1 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString1);
    int RowsAffected1 = (statement1.executeUpdate());
    statement1.close();
    statement2 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString2);
    int RowsAffected2 = (statement2.executeUpdate());
    statement2.close();
  }else{
    // Do nothing coz you can move up above 1  
  }
}

if (action.equals("move_down")){
  action="add";

  if (whichOrder != MaxValue){
    int CurrentOrder = whichOrder;
    int NewOrder = whichOrder + 1;
    String sqlString1 = "UPDATE msr_summary_notices set item_order = "+String.valueOf(NewOrder)+" WHERE item_order = "+String.valueOf(CurrentOrder);
    String sqlString2 = "UPDATE msr_summary_notices set item_order = "+String.valueOf(CurrentOrder)+" WHERE item_order = "+String.valueOf(NewOrder)+" AND absid <>"+rowid;
    statement1 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString1);
    int RowsAffected1 = (statement1.executeUpdate());
    statement1.close();
    statement2 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString2);
    int RowsAffected2 = (statement2.executeUpdate());
    statement2.close();
  }else{
    // Do nothing coz you can move down below MaxValue  

  }
}
```

Finally, here is the JavaScript function that shows/hide the rows on mouseout and the functionality to print out the rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showRow(RowId){

 var Row = document.getElementById("tr_"+RowId);
 Row.style.backgroundColor="#CCCCFF";
 //console.debug(Row);

}
function hideRow(RowId){

     var Row = document.getElementById("tr_"+RowId);
     Row.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";

}


 if ((action.equals("move_up"))||(action.equals("move_down"))){ 
     out.println("showRow("+rowid+")");
    //console.log(RowId);
}


</script>

</head>
```

I did a lot of research and I think the problem can be in the session that could be badly handled. Also, if the "item_order" in the DB remains messy (same item_order for multiple rows) I am not too bothered about it, as the main expected result is for the User Interface to show proper order of the rows.